# Notation in modulo groups

Tags: group-theory, notation

What does ${\Bbb Z}_m^*$ mean? I know that $\Bbb Z_m$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z$ but the asterisk tripped me up.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context, but usually it means the group of multiplicative units in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ (here thought of as a ring, rather than merely an abelian group).

Comment: Oh this was the notation used for the Euler theorem.

Comment: That sounds promising - $\varphi(m)=|\mathbb{Z}_m^*|$.

Comment: Ah yes that's the theorem :)